# Update and then select updated rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, sql-limit

I have an application that selects row with a particular status and then starts processing these rows. However some long running processing can cause a new instance of my program to be started, selecting the same rows again because it haven't had time to update the status yet. So I'm thinking of selecting my rows and then updating the status to something else so they cannot be selected again. I have done some searching and got the impression that the following should work, but it fails.

```
  UPDATE table SET status = 5 WHERE status in 
  (SELECT TOP (10) * FROM table WHERE status = 1)

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

**TLDR:** Is it possible to both select and update rows at the same time? (The order doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [an `output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to `update` the rows and then return them as if they were `select`ed.

As for updating the top 100 rows only, a safe approach is to use a cte to select the relevant rows first (I assumed that column `id` can be used to order the rows):

```
with cte as (select top (100) * from mytable where status = 1 order by id)
update cte set status = 5 output inserted.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly go for UPDATE statement. It will generate exclusive lock on the row and other concurrent transactions cannot read this row.

[More information on locks](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server)

> **Exclusive locks:** Exclusive locks are used to lock data being modified by one transaction thus preventing modifications by other
> concurrent transactions. You can read data held by exclusive lock only
> by specifying a NOLOCK hint or using a read uncommitted isolation
> level. Because DML statements first need to read the data they want to
> modify you'll always find Exclusive locks accompanied by shared locks
> on that same data.

```
UPDATE TOP(10) table 
SET status = 5 WHERE status =1
```